# How many times whille loop will be executed when we double the value?

Tags: time-complexity, loops

Consider this loop:

```
for i = 1 to n
 j = i
 while j < n
  j = j + j
 end while
end for
```

How many times the `while` loop will execute? I was thinking that if we denote by $c$ number of time loop will execute then in each iteration $j$ would be equal to $2^{c-1}i < n$, then taking logarithm we get $c<log_2{n} - log_2{i} + 1$ though I'm not sure this is helpful. I want to use this in sum so I'd like it to be natural.

Comment: What you did is perfectly ok. When you sum everything up, you get there an nlogn term, as well as a $\sum_{i=1}^n \log(i)$ term, which is $\Theta(n\log(n))$, which is *smaller* than just $n\log(n)$ but still bigger than $0.000001n\log(n)$, which means that also $c$ in this question can be bounded similarly. Thus $c=\Theta(n\log(n))$

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know how to proceed with this ;) You could write this as an answer, then I would be able to accept it.

Comment: @nirshahar, did I understand correctly that the running time is $\Theta(n \log n)$? This is not correct - it is actually $\Theta(n)$ for the same reasons why Build-Heap is $\Theta(n)$.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding something. The running time *is* $\Theta(n\log(n))$. The reasoning behind `BuildHeap` for taking $\Theta(n)$ is (if I remember correctly) that  $\frac{n}{2^k}$ values would need to run $k$ in time, so essentially there are more items that require less time than items that require more time. Here, there is no such "bias", since the bias came from the "shape" of the heap. So the running time here is $\Theta(n\log(n))$

Comment: @nirshahar, (please reference me when replying so that I can get a notification). "$\frac n {2^k}$  values would need to run $k$ in time" - this is exactly what happens here. $i \in [n/2, n)$ requires $1$ cycle, $i \in [n/4, n/2)$ requires $2$ cycles, etc.

Comment: @Dmitry Oh yea my bad. You are totally right. What I said is correct, **only if** the constant for $\sum_{i=1}^n \log(i) = O(n\log(n))$ is *strictly less than 1*, and I think its not that case. So, the running time should indeed be $\Theta(n)$ as you described